# PubsubJs and *this* is undefined when subscribing to a message

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

I have the following code:

```
    someClass1 = function () {
        this.doStuff = function () {
            PubSub.publish('topic1', { id: 1 });
        }
    }

    someClass2 = function () {
        this.forename = 'bob2';
        PubSub.subscribe("topic1", function (msg, data) {
            log(msg, data, this.forename);
        });
    }

    function log() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }

    var c1 = new someClass1();
    var c2 = new someClass2();
    c1.doStuff();
```

and I am using the pubsubjs library (https://github.com/federico-lox/pubsub.js)

The code is simple - publish a message and handle it in another class (someClass2) using PubSub

My question is that when I publish a message and handle it in someClass2, *this* is undefined. This occurs at the line: log(msg, data, this.forename);

This means I cant access any of the someClass2 properties/functions. What do I need to do to get the *this* to not be undefined? Is this possible? Are they other libraries that will help? Am I doing it wrong....

All help apprenticed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an unbound function to `subscribe`. Such a function has "no idea" about `this`. You have to bind it:

```
    PubSub.subscribe("topic1", (function (msg, data) {
        log(msg, data, this.forename);
    }).bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks. This took me a while to figure out. This helped to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind. It makes sense when I think about it now

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not what you expect inside the callback, just cache a copy of `this` as another variable outside:

```
someClass2 = function () {
    this.forename = 'bob2';
    var that = this;
    PubSub.subscribe("topic1", function (msg, data) {
        log(msg, data, that.forename);
    });
}
```

Comment: This (no pun intended!) works - but I am unsure why. Can you explain?

Comment: @Ilyas actually georg explained better in his answer. The function you passed to `subscribe` is not bound to any `this`. My answer simply stores a reference inside a variable which remains in scope. georg's answer binds the function to `this` so that within the function it now has a meaning. IMO my answer is simple, georg's answer is ostensibly the *right* way to solve your problem.